# agrupar registros com mesmo valor de uma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql

possuo uma tabela chamada **lojas**, essa tabela possui: ..., nome_loja e loja_categoria, exemplo:

> ```
> nome_loja | loja_categoria
> --------------------------
>     loja1 | roupas
>     loja2 | brinquedos
>     loja3 | roupas
> ```

o que gostaria de fazer é agrupar os registros com o mesmo nome de categoria, case insensitive se possível, com o resultado sendo um array associativo com o nome das categorias, algo assim:

> ```
> roupas => (
>    loja1,
>    loja3
> ),
> brinquedos => (
>    loja2
> )
> ```

Comment: já tentou o `select` com `group by` por nome_loja?

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo? usei o GROUP BY loja_categoria, ele só trouxe um resultado

Comment: qual linguagem está usando? Acho que você pode receber do _mysql_ e tratar (agrupar) via código, não?!

Comment: Estou usando PHP, se não for viável usando SQL...

Comment: O que você deseja fazer é melhor fazer via código mesmo.

Comment: group_concat   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Como seria a query, motta?

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando o Mysql da para utilizar o comando Group By

```
SELECT * FROM lojas GROUP BY loja_categoria
```

Ou você pode utilizar o comando distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT nome_categoria, nome_loja FROM lojas
```

Comment: retornou normal, como se fosse um select simples